# Is the mercurial default glob matching syntax configurable?

Tags: mercurial, glob, hgrc

To run a command on a single file, I recently realized I can do this:

```
hg log relglob:UniqueFilename
```

instead of:

```
hg log some/really/deep/directory/hierarchy/UniqueFilename
```

I'd like to take this one step further and make relglob the default matching syntax.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible with a configuration option. You could change the match default from relpath to relglob: http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/8bc4ad7e34c8/mercurial/cmdutil.py#l272

But I'm really not sure it is a good idea, for example what if you have several files with the same name?

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I agree, it's not a good default, but I also think it's reasonable to allow a user to override it.